# Structuring ASP,NET MVC application for large web sites

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, architecture

I have a generic question about what best practices exist to structure ASP.NET MVC applications.

The problem I'm thinking of is that we have quite a large web site and at the moment the structure I'm thinking about is to create a separate MVC project for logically separated part (thoug they have common UI layout) of web site and then combine them using load balancer mapping. The reason for that is that different teams are working on these parts and this way they can be released separately without interfering with each other.

However, it doesn't feel natural to ASP.NET MVC development and one MVC project per site looks like more natural approach. Though than it's a bit unclear how to release parts of the web sites independently.

Please share your thoughts.

Thanks!

Comment: You might be looking for the term "Microservice architecture".

Comment: Thanks a lot Simon! Will do some reading about it

Comment: @SimonWhitehead, Thank you Simon! It is what I am looking for as well:)

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer a singe Web project and structure this project in a way it would be easy to understand with other guys. If you want to structure your application logically it worth to look at [MVC areas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793(v=vs.100).aspx).

Some other tips:

- During the development of this application try to keep controllers
  as small/granular as you can.
- Your business logic should be stored in a [service layer](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/serviceLayer.html)
- Use nuget for all third party server side libraries
- Use [bower or npm](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/introducinggulpgruntbowerandnpmsupportforvisualstudio.aspx) for third party client side libraries
- Use some kind of ORM, i prefer Entity Framework with code first approach
- It is good to have a [Database Project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/xee70aty(v=vs.100).aspx) (i usually start with the database architecture and then generate entity framework mapping/classes reversibly with T4 templates - there is a nice extension for this http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d)

Comment: Thanks @MajoB What about release management? How to divide responcibility between different teams and not to retest the whole solution when other team are releasing changes in their part.

Comment: @lostaman It could be handled by version control system and good branching model http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/. In other words always have a stable master branch, which is ready to release any time of the day :)

Comment: It will still require to retest the whole site before releasing things.

Comment: @lostaman yes for sure and that is why we have unit and integration tests :) Also continuous builds with test automation and continuous deploys to test environment will help a lot.

Comment: Yeah.... We might struggle here and it's not in my power to change atm :(